# Losing syntax coloring with F# Power Tools, reinstall helps, looking for easier solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#

I have to admit, I have grown quite accustomed to using [F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) in my everyday F#-coding. Life wouldn't be the same without it.

Every now and then, usually after some days or weeks, I lose syntax coloring and some other features (F12 go to member stopped working as well).

Earlier I fixed it by reinstalling Power Tools, but I don't know whether the reinstall fixed it or the forced refresh of some file in VS. Just restart/recompile etc doesn't help.

In my C++ days there was a browse information file I could delete, something similar here maybe? Any ideas where to look?

Comment: I have similar issues every so often. Workarounds on my local: 1. Switching between dark and light color themes, 2. Closing and reopening the file(s). The best thing to do though is to look up the issues on GitHub and maybe even open one...

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis, yes, but I'd rather do that once I have a reproducible example. I have no idea what triggers it yet. I just tried switching themes, but it didn't work... In my case some classes seem to be resolved while others aren't. Some react to F12, others don't (all within sln). I suspect VS2015, actually (caching of some sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to update/answer my own old lingering question:*

Since the event of F# 4.1 earlier this year and Visual Studio 2017 coming out, F# PowerTools have been incorporated and much improved. While there are still uses with syntax coloring, it is now a community effort supported by Microsoft and it is looking better almost every nightly build.